# One to one and monotonic function

Tags: functions

Consider $f$ is continuous. We know that if $f$ is monotonic then $f$ is also one to one But can we conclude if $f$ is one to one then $f$ is also monotonic ? (If it's true how we can prove it?)

Comment: No, the injective property is not enough. Hint: think of a discontinuous example.

Comment: $f$ is a function from what into what? Consider a non continuous example...

Comment: $f$ is continuous

Comment: this depends on the domain (consider $f$ defined on $(0,1)\cup (2,3)$)

Comment: Is $f$ a function from a subset of the reals to the reals and is the domain connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous on a connected interval and one-to-one, it will be monotonic. If not there are $a<b< c $ such that $f(a)<f(b)>f(c)$ or similar numbers with reverse inequalities. 
Now by the mean value theorem each $\max\{f(a), f(c)\} <x<f(b) $ will have at least two counter images.

Comment: Can you explain the second part of your answer with an example ?

Comment: @S.H.W if $f$ is continuous, $a<b$ and $f(a) < x < f(b)$ there is, by the mean value theorem, some $ d\in (a,b)$ such that $f(d) = x$. The same applies on the interval $(b,c)$